# My title is hiding on some screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Trying to figure out why my title is hiding on some screens, would this have to do with responsive design? Here is the link:

http://aswanson.net/KiloArt/visions.html

Comment: even after taking the <p> tags away it still needs a margin to display correctly

Comment: i updated the link with no margins and it does not work

Comment: Title normal in the middle in full length, `text align: center` as is. Dropdown - `position: absolute; top: little bit; right: also little bit'. That's it.

Comment: what do you mean little bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS line 14 .title, you a negative margin in there.. that's why..

```
margin-top: -9%;
```

DIRTY FIX for your layout:

- set marging of header1  > p to zero

add this:

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And again, this a dirty solution. If you have time then work on improving your layout.

Btw, don't add a negative margin top on your header, adjust the margin of the `<p>` inside your header title so you won't be having the same issue again... you can set it to 0 or a little more than that.

Comment: i updated the link with no margins and it does not work

Comment: well there is a lot of room for improvement on your layout. but check my update. made a dirty fix.. a good way to improve this is by restructuring  your layout..  @DeemStarr

Comment: Remember the 'p' tag creates a space above it by default. You can replace it with the 'li' tag if it is set for 'no-bullets'. This is not an answer as much as an explanation of how the 'p' tag works. It is mostly for actual paragraphs, multiple lines of text..

Comment: lol.. set width to 80%.. and don't forget the margin on your title `<p>` tag.

Comment: ok that worked, and i took away the <p> tag, but it still didnt solve the problem of the header being pushed too far down.

Comment: there's a default margin on top and below your <p> tag.. that's why I said to set the margin of `.title p { margin: 0 }` or some other values.

Comment: ok this was all very helpful and it is working much better now, thanks all!